# Attempting to remove individual commit thats not pushed to main branch

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I am currently using rstudio cloud and have run into an error regarding my .Rdata file being too large to push. I made 9 major commits that aren't pushed, but I am pretty sure the last 2 are the ones that caused this error. Is there a way I can remove the last 2 commits and revert to the 6th commit?

Comment: It is recommended that you accept the answer if it satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp branch where you are (just in case) and reset --hard

```
git branch temp # set new branch temp where I am
git reset --hard HEAD~2 # get rid of the last two revisions
```

If you like it, `git branch -D temp`. If you don't and you want to go back: `git reset --hard temp`.

Make sure you have no things laying around your working tree because reset --hard clears up all files in the revision and sets them as the revision you are asking to reset to.

Comment: Great! How about checking it as _the answer_? ;)